# DensityPlot with text

Tags: plotting, color, labeling

Is there any way to generate something like the image (so label chunks of the `DensityPlot` with the function value? (the image is really more of a list density plot, but both cases are of interest):
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that a density plot is ideal for achieving the image above. I'd us a different approach in this case.

Let's start generating the data:

```
max = 50;
entries = RandomReal[{0, max}, {24, 7}];
dim = Dimensions@entries;
```

We can now create the final table:

```
head = {"", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday"};

temp = Transpose[{Range[0, 23]}~Join~Transpose@entries];
table = Prepend[temp, head];
```

And we can assign a background color to each cell:

```
background =
  Join[{Lighter@Blue, None},
   {Flatten[Table[
      {i, j} -> ColorData["WatermelonColors"][table[[i, j]]/max]
      , {i, 2, 1 + dim[[1]]}, {j, 2, 1 + dim[[2]]}
      ], 1]}
   ];
```

of course, you can use any other color scheme other than WatermelonColors, or create a new one as described in other posts here.

Finally, let's generate the table (the frame settings are a bit verbose, but I couldn't find a more clever way to do it):

```
frame = {None, 
   None, {{{1, -1}, {1, -1}} -> True}~
    Join~(({1, #} -> True) & /@ Range[8])~
    Join~(({#, 1} -> True) & /@ Range[25])};

Grid[table, Frame -> frame, Background -> background, 
 ItemStyle -> {{Directive[White, Bold], 
    Automatic}, {Directive[White, Bold], Automatic}}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Very cool, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here is an approach similar to @Fraccalo's, but using [`Item`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Item.html) to specify the styles, and [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) to attach the headers. I usually find `Item` to be more readable in cases like this, since the style is attached directly to each item and doesn't need to be matched up with several other matrices.

```
max = 50;
entries = RandomReal[{0, max}, {24, 7}];
dim = Dimensions@entries;

styledEntries = Map[
  Item[#, Background -> ColorData["WatermelonColors"][#/max]] &,
  entries,
  {2}
 ];

head = {"", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

rowHead = Range[0, 23];

{styledHead, styledRowHead} = Map[
  Item[#, Background -> Lighter@Blue, Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> Directive[White, Bold]] &,
  {head, rowHead}, 
  {2}
 ];

table = ArrayFlatten[{List /@ TakeDrop[styledHead, 1], {List /@ styledRowHead, styledEntries}}];

Grid[table]
```

[image]

As you can see, it is very apparent which style is applied to which item and how they are computed.

Comment: Cool! What if I wanted to typeset the numbers, in say, PercentForm? Do I convert `entries` to PercentForm first? It seems more natural to do it in `Item`...

Comment: Never mind, what I suggest above does NOT work, because the entries are not numbers anymore, but doing it inside the Item does.

Answer (score 7):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[100, {24, 7}];

days = {"", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",  "Saturday", "Sunday"};
```

#### MatrixPlot

An alternative approach using `MatrixPlot` with labels added with the option `Epilog`:

```
table = Prepend[MapIndexed[Prepend[#, ToString[#2[[1]] - 1]] &, data], days];

scaled = PadLeft[Rescale[data], 1 + Dimensions[data], Blue];

epilog = MapIndexed[Text[Style[# /. x_?NumericQ -> Round[x, 0.01], 12, 
  If[NumericQ[#] && .25 < Rescale[#, MinMax@data, {0, 1}] < .75, Black, White]], #2 - .5]&,
  Reverse /@ Transpose@table, {2}];

mp = MatrixPlot[scaled, 
  ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit", 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ImageSize -> 1 -> {80, 20}, 
  Mesh -> All,
  Epilog -> epilog, 
  Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Add a legend:

```
legend =  BarLegend[{"RedGreenSplit", MinMax @ data}, LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 400}];
Legended[mp, legend]
```

[image]

Use `ColorFunction -> (Opacity[.5,ColorData["RedGreenSplit"]@#]&)` and change `epilog` to

```
epilog = MapIndexed[Text[Style[# /. x_?NumericQ -> Round[x, 0.01], 12, 
   If[StringQ @ #, White, Black]], #2 - .5] &, 
   Reverse /@ Transpose@table, {2}];
```

to get

[image]

#### DensityHistogram + WeightedData

If it is ok to have row and column headers as plain text labels, you can also use `DensityHistogram` after constructing a [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) object from `data`:

```
wd = WeightedData[Join @@ MapIndexed[Reverse@#2 &, data, {2}], Join @@ Reverse[data]];

{leftticks, topticks} = {MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], 
   Style[24 - #, 14, Bold, FontOpacity -> 1, FontColor -> Blue]} &, Range[24]], 
   MapIndexed[{#2[[1]] - 1, 
      Style[#, 14, Bold, FontOpacity -> 1, FontColor -> Blue]} &,   days]};
```

***Using a custom [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html)***

```
assoc = AssociationThread[N@wd["InputData"], wd["Weights"]];

cEF = {ChartElementData["Rectangle"][##], 
    Text[Style[#, 12, If[.25 <= Rescale[#, MinMax@data, {0, 1}] <= .75, Black, 
         White]] & @ assoc[Mean @ Transpose[#]], Mean @ Transpose[#]]} &;

dp1 = DensityHistogram[wd, Reverse[Dimensions@data] - 1, 
   ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit", 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive["LineOpacity" -> 0], 
   FrameTicks -> {{leftticks, False}, {False, topticks}}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive["LineColor" -> White], Frame -> True, 
   BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Gray], 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01], 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 600, 
   ChartElementFunction -> cEF];

Legended[dp1, legend]
```

[image]

***Post-processing `DensityHistogram` output***:

Alternatively, we can post-process `DensityHistogram` output to replace tooltips with `Text` labels:

```
dp2 = DensityHistogram[wd, Reverse[Dimensions@data] - 1, 
   ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit", 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive["LineOpacity" -> 0], 
   FrameTicks -> {{leftticks, False}, {False, topticks}}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive["LineColor" -> White], Frame -> True, 
   BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Gray], PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01], 
   ImageSize -> 600];

labels = dp2 /. Tooltip[c_, t_, ___] :> Text[Style[Round[t, 0.01], 12, 
    If[.25 <= Rescale[t, MinMax @ data, {0, 1}] <= .75, Black, White]], 
    Cases[c, Rectangle[a_, b_, ___] :> (a + b)/2, All][[1]], {Center, Center}] 

Legended[Show[dp2, labels], legend]
```

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to create a column vector of colors and associated ranges so that readers can easily link the colors in the table to the corresponding ranges.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, not sure I understand the "link the colors in the table to the corresponding ranges" part.

Comment: I mean if one looks at the table, one needs to quickly see the interval of the data associated with the color in the table. For example, I see a dark green in the table and the data in the dark green cells range from 99.79 to 90.78. Would it be possible to insert a label, for example, "dark green - 90<...<100" and so on under the table? I hope my explanation is understanable.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, maybe adding a legend `BarLegend[{"RedGreenSplit", MinMax@data}]`? (making a `SwatchLegend` with ranges is more work)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I will work out using your suggestion. Tugrul