# TableView: How to change column headings?

Tags: graphics, programming, probability-or-statistics, data

I am not even sure whether it is possible. I would like to change column headings of TableView output to letters such as A, B, C etc instead of 1,2,3. Here is an example:

```
RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{10, 20}], {10, 3}] // TableView
```

[image]

I want the results to look like an excel spreadsheet as follows:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: using the undocumented TableView is not advised: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170036/undocumented-tableview-function
I suggest you to look into different visualisation formats. In this thread (and in many others) there are other options: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208511/densityplot-with-text/208514#208514

Comment: @ Fraccalo, Thank you for your comment. However, my purpose is different from just data visualization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be efficient but could be a good starting point. It works for data up to 26 columns. If you need more columns, you can modify the function.

```
    tableView[data_] := Module[{rowheadings, columnheading, output},
      rowheadings = Flatten[{Range[1, Length[data]]}];
      columnheading =Flatten[{"", CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[1 ;; Dimensions[data] 
                     [[2]]]]}];
      output = Prepend[Join[List /@ rowheadings, Map[Style[NumberForm[#, 6]] &, data, {-1}], 2], 
             columnheading];
      Grid[output, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.9],
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Background -> {{GrayLevel[.8], None}, {GrayLevel[.8], None}}]
      ]
```

Here is an example:

```
data = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{10, 20}], {7, 5}];
tableView[data]
```

[image]

Comment: @ ramesh, it definitely helps. Thank you.

Comment: @ DLT, I am glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the options of TableView it seems like it's not possible.

```
Options[TableView]
```

> {Alignment -> {Automatic, Automatic}, AllowedDimensions -> Automatic, 
>    Appearance -> Automatic, AppearanceElements -> All, 
>    Background -> Automatic, BaselinePosition -> Automatic, 
>    BaseStyle -> {}, ContentPadding -> True, 
>    DefaultBaseStyle -> "TableView", Enabled -> Automatic, 
>    FieldSize -> {{1., 5.}, {1., 1.}}, FrameMargins -> Automatic, 
>    ImageMargins -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
>    Scrollbars -> {Automatic, Automatic}, ScrollPosition -> {0., 0.}, 
>    Spacings -> Automatic}

Anyway, as I suggested in the comment, the use of TableView is not advised as it causes crashes and is still under development.

Comment: Looking at `Options[TableView]` today in version 12.3.1 shows that there is a new Header option. And yes it does exactly what is being asked. Try `TableView[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{10, 20}], {10, 3}], 
 Headers -> {{"A", "B", "C"}, Automatic}]`

Comment: @GustavoDelfino perhaps you can add this as an answer?