# Generate better looking correlation table

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation, data, correlation

I have this code:

```
AllData = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/7RLL1Jw8", "Table"];
Temp0 = 25;
Do[Spec[2*i] = AllData[[All, (2*i + 1) ;; (2*i + 2)]], {i, 0, 8}];
Do[TotCts[2*i] = {5*i + Temp0, 
Integrate[Interpolation[Spec[2*i], InterpolationOrder -> 3][x], {x, 682,715}], 
Integrate[Interpolation[Spec[2*i], InterpolationOrder -> 3][x], {x, 715,745}], 
Integrate[Interpolation[Spec[2*i], InterpolationOrder -> 3][x], {x,745,770}]}, {i, 0, 8}];
DataPoints = N[Table[TotCts[2*i], {i, 0, 8}]];
mem = {●, ■, ◆};
cdata = Transpose[DataPoints[[All, 2 ;; 4]]];
ccm = Correlation[Transpose@cdata]; 
p2 = Column[{GraphicsRow[mem, ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> All, 
BaseStyle -> Directive["TR", FontSize -> 16, Black]],Row[{GraphicsColumn[mem, ImageSize -> {200/3, 200}, Frame -> All, 
  BaseStyle -> Directive["TR", FontSize -> 16, Black]], 
 Overlay[{ArrayPlot[ccm, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["GrayTones"][(1 + #)/2] &), 
    Frame -> None, Mesh -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    ImageSize -> {200, 200}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
   GraphicsGrid[Map[NumberForm[#, 2] &, ccm, {2}], 
    ImageSize -> {200, 200}, 
    BaseStyle -> Directive["TR", FontSize -> 16, Black]]}]}]}, Alignment -> Right, Spacings -> 0]
```

Which generates this:

[image]

Is it possible to output a better looking table without those gaps between the top row and left column to the main table?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Grid

```
ClearAll[labeledGrid]
labeledGrid[cs_: "GrayTones", is_: {80, 80}, 
  sty_: Directive["TR", FontSize -> 16, Black]] := 
    Module[{tbl = Map[Item[Pane[Style[If[NumericQ@#, NumberForm[#, 2], #],  sty], 
       Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> is], 
       Background -> If[NumericQ@#, ColorData[cs][(1 + #)/2], None]] &, 
     Prepend[Join[List /@ #2, #, 2], Prepend[#2, ""]], {2}]},
    Grid[tbl, Dividers -> {All, All, {{1, 1} -> False}}, ##3]] &;

labeledGrid[][ccm, mem, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

```
labeledGrid["Rainbow", {50, 50}][ccm, mem, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

#### ArrayPlot

```
ClearAll[labeledArrayPlot]
labeledArrayPlot[cs_: "GrayTones"] :=  Module[{epilog = 
      MapIndexed[Text[Style[# /. x_?NumericQ -> Round[x, 0.01], 
          Directive["TR", FontSize -> 16, Black]], #2 - .5] &, 
       Reverse /@ Transpose@ Prepend[Join[List /@ #2, #, 2], Prepend[#2, ""]], {2}]},
    ArrayPlot[ArrayPad[#, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, White]  , 
     ColorFunction -> ( ColorData[cs][(1 + #)/2] &), 
     Epilog -> epilog, ##3,
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 1 -> 80]] &;

labeledArrayPlot[][ccm, mem]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomReal[1, {7, 7}];
labels = StringTake[#, 3] & /@ RandomWord[7];

labeledArrayPlot["Rainbow"][mat, labels, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

How about using `MatrixPlot`?

```
epilog = MapIndexed[Text[Style[Round[#, .01], 10], #2 - 1/2] &, Transpose@Reverse@ccm, {2}];
ticks = Transpose[{Range@Length@mem, mem}];

MatrixPlot[ccm,
 Epilog -> epilog,
 FrameTicks -> {ticks, ticks, ticks, ticks},
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["GrayTones"][(1 + #)/2] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Readapting my answer here: [DensityPlot with text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208511/densityplot-with-text/208514#208514)

```
dim = Dimensions@ccm;

temp = Transpose[{mem}~Join~Transpose@Round[ccm, .01]];
table = Prepend[temp, Flatten@{"", mem}];

background = 
  Join[{None, 
    None}, {Flatten[
     Table[{i, j} -> ColorData["GrayTones"][table[[i, j]]], {i, 2, 
       1 + dim[[1]]}, {j, 2, 1 + 3}], 1]}];

Grid[table
 , Frame -> All
 , Background -> background
 , Alignment -> Center
 , ItemSize -> All
 , Spacings -> {3, 4}
 , ItemStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Bold], Automatic}
   , {Directive[Black, Bold], Automatic}}]
```

> [image]